# Unable to move current document aside for file - Xcode Git crash

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I am trying to commit a file into my source control but all a get when I am trying to commit the certain file(only), Xcode crashes.

It is not a new project, everything is perfectly functional on other files.

Here is the bug report I get after Xcode crashes:

```
SSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7720/IDEKit/SourceControl/WindowControllers/IDESourceControlMergeController.m:283
Details:  Unable to move current document aside for file /Volumes/Projects/IOS/PROJECT/PROJECT/file.m. Error: “file.m” couldn’t be moved to “PROJECT” because an item with the same name already exists.
```

*This is just a section of the report that I believe is relevant to my question. Please let me know if you need more info*

Restarted both mac and Xcode individually.

Can anyone let me know what can be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating to:

- show hidden files
- Project directory
- .git directory(hidden)
- Rename index.lock file to index.lock.old

This will solve the issue of not been able to commit into your source control system